# There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done.[wireshark]

Tags: networking, wireshark

I'm trying to use wireshark, my OS is debian, but when i want to have a capture it doesn't work , and i get this message: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done.
NB: ~ I do have connected interfaces.
    ~If I try to run wireshark using a shell as root i get:  No protocol specified

(wireshark:4515): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

So what's the problem?
thanks for yur replies

Answer (score 1):

> my OS is debian

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
```

and then log out and log back in again.